# Autoscaling Group doesn't respect ELB health checks after CodeDeploy redeploy

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy

I encountered very strange behaviour. 
Given:
1. Autoscaling group with ELB health checks behind and ELB (Application)
2. If it is manually created a group and ELB set unhealthy status for some instances they will propagate to ASG.
3. CodeDeploy with blue/green pattern replaces the previous ASG with its copy. All setting refer to ELB health checks. But... They don't actually work. If instances are​ unhealthy in ELB it is still healthy in ASG forever.